# Does not use passive listeners to improve scrolling performance (Lighthouse Report)

Tags: javascript, jquery, lighthouse

A recent Lighthouse Report flagged the following issue.

> Does not use passive listeners to improve scrolling performance

It also mentions...

> Consider marking your touch and wheel event listeners as `passive` to improve your page's scroll performance.

How do I resolve this issue? It appears to be related to jQuery.

Comment: https://web.dev/uses-passive-event-listeners/

Answer (score 98):

There was a long thread on this topic in https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2871 in 2016

In short:

- jQuery can't add support to passive listeners.
- Is expected that this is added in jQuery 4 (4 years and still in 3.5.x)
- The proposed fix is to add this code right after jQuery load:

---

```
jQuery.event.special.touchstart = {
        setup: function( _, ns, handle ){
            this.addEventListener("touchstart", handle, { passive: true });
        }
    };
```

**UPDATE 2021: Add the following code after jquery. This will fix it and removes the Pagespeed warning**

```
jQuery.event.special.touchstart = {
    setup: function( _, ns, handle ) {
        this.addEventListener("touchstart", handle, { passive: !ns.includes("noPreventDefault") });
    }
};
jQuery.event.special.touchmove = {
    setup: function( _, ns, handle ) {
        this.addEventListener("touchmove", handle, { passive: !ns.includes("noPreventDefault") });
    }
};
jQuery.event.special.wheel = {
    setup: function( _, ns, handle ){
        this.addEventListener("wheel", handle, { passive: true });
    }
};
jQuery.event.special.mousewheel = {
    setup: function( _, ns, handle ){
        this.addEventListener("mousewheel", handle, { passive: true });
    }
};
```

Comment: I added this in script tag following the script tag which adds jquery-3.3.1.min.js. The lighthouse performance won't increacse still. Did anyone here find a solution to actually get rid of the report " Does not use passive listeners to improve scrolling performance"

Comment: Is the goal to make the lighthouse report look good for your boss/client or to make the page actually perform better?

Comment: @squarecandy i think both points are relevant for many people ;)

Comment: I've added the code right after jQuery load (v3.2.1), but PageSpeed still mentions about passive listeners

Comment: this "fix" must be deficient somewhere or wouldn't JQ team have just "added it"?

Comment: .includes is not supported by all browsers

Comment: @escape-llc adding a patch to your project and testing to make sure it works on that project is way less complicated than updating a js library used by (literally) half the internet. The issue thread from the jQuery github that's linked in this answer explains that a robust solution would mean a major overhaul to `.on` with breaking changes.

Comment: You have saved me from so much stress! Thank you :)

Comment: Working on 2022, thanks!

Comment: What exactly does "after jquery" mean? After the link? After it has been loaded?

Answer (score 26):

This has done the trick !

```
// Passive event listeners
jQuery.event.special.touchstart = {
    setup: function( _, ns, handle ) {
        this.addEventListener("touchstart", handle, { passive: !ns.includes("noPreventDefault") });
    }
};
jQuery.event.special.touchmove = {
    setup: function( _, ns, handle ) {
        this.addEventListener("touchmove", handle, { passive: !ns.includes("noPreventDefault") });
    }
};
```

Comment: Is there an unofficial jQuery distribution with this fix? Would it prevent the lighthouse warning?

Comment: think you need to remove the `!` before `ns.includes`

Comment: prevents the lighthouse warning at the time of this comment with jquery 3.6.0

Answer (score -5):

How to make event listeners passive to improve scrolling performance. To solve this issue-:

1. Go to the theme core file.
2. Look for header.php or you can use a plugin to insert code into the header.
3. Copy the code and paste it into the header.php file.
4. If you are going to use the code into header.php, I would highly recommend you to use the PHP opening and closing tag.

[image]

```js
  <script>!function(e){"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(e):e()}(function(){var e,t=["scroll","wheel","touchstart","touchmove","touchenter","touchend","touchleave","mouseout","mouseleave","mouseup","mousedown","mousemove","mouseenter","mousewheel","mouseover"];if(function(){var e=!1;try{var t=Object.defineProperty({},"passive",{get:function(){e=!0}});window.addEventListener("test",null,t),window.removeEventListener("test",null,t)}catch(e){}return e}()){var n=EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener;e=n,EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener=function(n,o,r){var i,s="object"==typeof r&&null!==r,u=s?r.capture:r;(r=s?function(e){var t=Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(e,"passive");return t&&!0!==t.writable&&void 0===t.set?Object.assign({},e):e}(r):{}).passive=void 0!==(i=r.passive)?i:-1!==t.indexOf(n)&&!0,r.capture=void 0!==u&&u,e.call(this,n,o,r)},EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener._original=e}});</script>
```

Comment: When did anyone ever say anything about this being WordPress?

Comment: The code is legit and has solved the issue on my end. I just didn't add it to the header I just added it with other js code. Thanks :)