# How to fix "Does not use passive listeners..." from google maps API [VUE]

Tags: vue.js, google-maps, nuxt.js, lighthouse, passive-event-listeners

I'm using vue2-google-maps on my project.
In my lighthouse report, there are diagnostics that say "Does not use passive listeners to improve scrolling performance" from maps.googleapis.com.
do you guys know how to resolve it? Thanks.

This is the image from my lighthouse report:

[image]

Comment: this discussion might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60357083/does-not-use-passive-listeners-to-improve-scrolling-performance-lighthouse-repo

Comment: @Narendra were you able to find a workaround for vue without jQuery?