# How do I safely mark the listener as passive and keep it working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm trying to optimize the website performance according to the Google PageSpeed recommendations. One of the advices is to set touch and wheel event listeners as passive, which is shown for the `jquery.min.js` file and its `a.addEventListener(n,g)` line.

When I add `{passive: true}` to the line like `a.addEventListener(n,g,{passive: true})`, some elements on the website using jQuery stop to work.

How do I safely mark the listener as passive and keep it working?

ps. jQuery v3.2.1

Comment: It looks like there is some data about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60357083/does-not-use-passive-listeners-to-improve-scrolling-performance-lighthouse-repo)

Answer (score 1):

1. You may need to confirm that `passive: true` is actually what you're looking for.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#parameters
2. It's likely a better idea to debouce the (what I'm assuming are) scroll-related events rather than much around with `addEventListener()` parameters.